# ajax not listing all files in directory

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am attempting to list all json files in a directory on my server like this:

```
listed_files = [];
function list_files() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "path_to_files/",
    success: function(data){
      $(data).find("a:contains('.json')").each(function(){
        // will loop through
        var files = $(this).attr("href");
        listed_files.push(files);
      });
     }
   });
}
```

It works, except it only lists 4 files when there are 6. The only thing I notice is that the 2 it misses have longer file names. What could cause this?

The files are named like this:

```
file_name_a_this_is_long.json
file_name_b_short.json
file_name_c_short.json
file_name_d_this_is_long.json
file_name_e_short.json
file_name_f_short.json
```

The file listing looks like this:

```
file_name_a_this_is_lo..>
file_name_b_short.json
file_name_c_short.json
file_name_d_this_is_lo..>
file_name_e_short.json
file_name_f_short.json
```

Comment: Can we see the directory listing page HTML source code? (AKA the HTML that your JavaScript is parsing).

Comment: there is none. It is listing what is in the directory.

Comment: Right click the page and click "View Source". Even directory listing pages have source code.

Comment: @Cybernetic: There are many kinds of listings that your server could produce. Please show us the HTML it sent.

Comment: @Cybernetic Just console.log(data) in the success function of your ajax call and show us what's in it

Comment: try `a[href*='.json']`

Comment: I see. So the longer file names are cut off in the listing with "..>" at the end. So the ajax cannot see the file extension. Only on the shorter filenames can it see them.

Comment: Well tough to match .json when it is not there...

Comment: Yes, that would be the problem.

Comment: I think you need to fix the server side script that is responsible to return the files list. I would also json_encode whatever is returned.

Answer (score -1):

As per @Marco's response, the server side script needed to return the results differently. Then the ajax can work as it should. The following PHP script will list files fully:

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if (($file != ".")
                && ($file != ".."))
            {
            $thelist .= '<LI><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
            }
        }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>

<P>List of files:</p>
<UL>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</UL>
```